# Deleting a char* crashing program

Tags: c++, char

```
char* str = "hello myname is Stack";
delete[] str;
```

Why is my program crashing? Is char* str allocated on the stack?

Comment: Strings literals have static storage duration. You can only ever `delete[]` what you've allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: Just because it's a pointer does not mean it needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's illegal to `delete[]` anything you didn't allocate with `new[]`. That's it.

And no, `str` doesn't *point to something* on the stack, but to a **string literal**, which is immutable and typically resides in a read-only segment.

Comment: so it will auto delete str at the end of function call?

Comment: @JavaNewb No, not the string literal. String literals have static storage duration. They last for the entire program. Why? Because they have to be stored in your executable somewhere and your executable is loaded into memory to be executed.

Comment: @JavaNewb `str`, yes, the string itself - no. But you needn't worry about it.

Comment: No. The literal will likely love for the entire lifetime of the containing module.

Comment: is it not a waist of memory?

Comment: @JavaNewb The pointer `str` will go out of scope and be destroyed, yes. However, that won't do anything to the memory it points at. In this case, that's good, because it points to some data that's supposed to live for the whole program run and may be referenced from many different places. Edit: It doesn't waste memory. The string literal has to be in the executable *somehow*. This particular approach actually saves memory, though in a different way: If the same string literal is used several times, it's only stored once.

Comment: @JavaNewb No it's not. It has to be stored somewhere.

Comment: @delnan "If the same string literal is used several times, it's only stored once" not necessarily. Not mandated.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, I'm referring to a particular implementation strategy. It's not the only possible one, though apparently by far the most common.

Comment: This talk of read-only memory is all very well; but most architectures don't actually enforce it. You can write to 'read-only' memory perfectly easily on most computers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `delete` something not allocated with `new`.  Additionally this string resides in read-only memory and cannot be deleted.

To see this, try compiling with -S.  For example.

```
// ex.c
int main(){
    const char * s = "hello my name is Stack";
}
```

When compiled with

```
gcc -S ex.c
```

You will get a file `ex.s` containing the following at the top:

```
    .file   "ex.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "hello my name is Stack"
    .text
```

As you can see, the string itself is in the assembly, it is not allocated at run time.  The literal resides in read-only memory (`.rodata`)when the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

Luchian has already described the problem, I want to give the probable reason it crashes.

The heap will have a stored list of what memory chunks it has already allocated; when you call `delete[]` it will try to find the piece of memory it previously allocated and return this chunk of memory to the unallocated heap. This will fail because you didn't allocate your variable on the heap. Having failed to find a valid bit of memory to deallocate it will then try to write to a null pointer and produce your crash.

Comment: The string isn't in the stack.